# C++ (g++) Compile Error, Expected "="/etc. Before 'MyWindow" (my class name)

Tags: c++, oop, class, g++, compiler-errors

I have a very strange problem and the following code wont compile:

```
#ifndef MYWINDOW_HPP_INCLUDED
#define MYWINDOW_HPP_INCLUDED

class MyWindow{

    private:
        WNDCLASSEX window_class;
        HWND window_handle;
        HDC device_context_handle;
        HGLRC open_gl_render_context;
        MSG message;
        BOOL quit;

    public:
        Window(int height=416, int width=544, WindowStyle window_style=WINDOWED);
        void Show();
        void Close();
        ~Window();

};

#endif // MYWINDOW_HPP_INCLUDED
```

I get the following error:
    error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'MyWindow'

I can't see any syntax errors here, although I coukd be wrong as I am very (very) new in c++. Thanks in advance, ell.

EDIT:
Yeah, I tried renaming my class to MyWindow from Window to solve the problem but it didn't work, I forgot to rename the constructor. I have updated the code now but that still hasn't solved the problem. Here is the only other code I have in my project, I linked it because adding al those spaces would take a while: 
 [here's the code](http://pastebin.com/uzQnX92w)

Comment: What headers are you including? Note that your constructor should be named MyWindow, not Window as you have it, but that wouldn't result in the error you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, silly me, I had main saved as a .c file instead of .cpp, resulting in Code::Blocks trying to compile it as in c instead of c++, thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your problem comes before the posted file. In the including file or a previous include.

Comment: This sometimes happens to me when I forget the semicolon after the class definition. It starts complaining about the class in the *next* included header.

Comment: With candidates being missing `;`, `}` etc.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things - you need to have:

```
 #include <windows.h>
```

somewhere in your code. And if:

```
 Window(int height=416, int width=544, WindowStyle window_style=WINDOWED);
```

is supposed to be a constructor, it should ne:

```
 MyWindow(int height=416, int width=544, WindowStyle window_style=WINDOWED);
```

Answer (score 1):

This header isn't being compiled as C++, so the compiler doesn't recognize "class" as a reserved word. I was getting this error, and it was because I was trying to include a C++ header in an Objective-C source file, and the solution was to use a stripped-down straight-C header for inclusion from Obj-C.

-- Fellow C++ noob who just ran into this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you're using `g++` rather than `gcc`?  It's a dumb question, but the `class` keyword in C++ isn't a keyword in C, which might trigger such a warning.  Untested theory, but I've run into that a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

You're using semi-colons after your function definitions. Remove them. (Referring to your pastebin code.)

Comment: If by definition you mean after the close curly brace after the actual function, I have tried removing these but it doesn't help